# jTable : How to split table cell in jTable using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have developed a ASP.net MVC project which will show Reports based on user selection.I am planing to display Tabledata using JTable ,but my problem is i cant split my table cell in jTable.

My Expected Table Structure,

[image]

I am passing JSON as Datasource to Jtable.

Is it possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

are you using from this [jTable](http://jtable.org/) in your project?
if yes, why you want to split table cells?

Comment: My table style is like what i have updated in my post.Here Col4 contains two values Sub1 and Sub2. My server is returning data like this.

Comment: are you using from this jTable in your project?